# Jasmine dependency injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, jasmine, karma-runner

I am really new to javascript and I am writing a few jasmine tests in a simple spec javascript. How do I introduce dependencies to jquery and underscore within this spec without using requireJS.?

```
describe( "Testing Karma and Jasmine", function () {

    describe("Hello world test", function() {
        it("says hello", function() {
            expect(testingJasmine()).toEqual("Hello world!");
        });
    });

});

describe('just checking', function() {

    it('works for app', function() {
        var el = $('<div></div>');

        var app = restify.createServer()
        app.render();

        expect(el.text()).toEqual('require.js up and running');
    });

    it('works for underscore', function() {
        // just checking that _ works
        expect(_.size([1,2,3])).toEqual(3);
    });

});
```

If you look at the code attached it is not able to resolve $(JQUERY) and _(UNDERSCORE) dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the files path in the [karma config file](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/configuration-file.html).

You can add the dependencies like this

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'scripts/libs/jquery.js,
  'scripts/libs/underscore.js
];
```

Check [this example config file](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/v0.8.5/test/client/karma.conf.js),

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem of injecting jQuery for jasmine testing.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a reference to the top of the file, like this:

```
/// <reference path="../js/libs/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" />
```

Or if you have multiple ones, you could add them all to a test reference file. Basically create a new JS file named _references.js in your test directory and in that file include and common JS files you need to include. Then you can include _references.js in all your tests.

```
/// <reference path="_references.js" />
```